# Create a view on Hive with Spark

Tags: view, pyspark, create-table

How can I create a view on Hive with Spark using pyspark ?

I have made some works on df that I have extracted from Hive with :

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

Now I want create a view or a table with what there are in df

Is it possible ?

Comment: Where do you want to create? Post is hard to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not convinced difference due to pyspark, also a pure answer to the title with a multi-table view of already existing tables:

```
spark.sql("create or replace view viewSO as select f1.orig as f1_orig, f2.orig as f2_orig, f2.dest as f2_dest from facts f1, facts f2 ")
spark.table("viewSO").printSchema

root
  |-- f1_orig: string (nullable = true)
  |-- f2_orig: string (nullable = true)
  |-- f2_dest: string (nullable = true)
```